# Iterate through items of an arbitrary layered dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, iterator

I have a dictionary in Python with an **increasing number of layers** in iterations.

I want to iterate through the values that exist in the last layer.

Suppose this dict:

```
d = {'a':{'a':2},'b':{'c':2},'x':{'a':2}}
#the intuitive solution is
for key1,val in d.items():
    for key2,val2 in val.items():
        #integer value in val2, HOORAY
```

Now if we add an layer the loop goes:

```
d = {'a':{'a':{'y':2}},'b':{'c':{'a':5}},'x':{'a':{'m':6}}}
#the intuitive solution is
for key1,val in d.items():
    for key2,val2 in val.items():
        for key3,val3 in val2.items():
             #integer value in val3
```

I look for a dynamic solution of arbitrary dimensions iteration

Consider the number of layers known and fixed for all elements in an iteration if that helps.

Additionally I like to know how an integer is mapped in the dict.

Comment: `sorted` has nothing to do with nested iterations. It simply orders a sequence of elements.

Comment: @Bakuriu I edited the description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is best solved using recursion:

```
def iter_leafs(d):
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            yield from iter_leafs(val)
        else:
            yield val
```

Example usage:

```
>>> d = {'a':{'a':{'y':2}},'b':{'c':{'a':5}},'x':{'a':{'m':6}}}
>>> list(iter_leafs(d))
[6, 5, 2]
```

If you also want to keep track of the keys:

```
def iter_leafs(d, keys=[]):
    for key, val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            yield from iter_leafs(val, keys + [key])
        else:
            yield keys + [key], val

>>> list(iter_leafs(d))
[(['x', 'a', 'm'], 6), (['b', 'c', 'a'], 5), (['a', 'a', 'y'], 2)]
```

Comment: Sweet yield! Python is great.. I expected black magic built-in function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might be off-base here because I'm not sure I exactly understand what you want, but this will get all the values in the last layer:

```
def get_values(my_dict):
    sub_vals = []
    actual_vals = []
    for val in my_dict.values():
        try:
            sub_vals += get_values(val)
        except AttributeError:
            actual_vals += [val]
    return sub_vals + actual_vals
```

Comment: If I had 50 nested dictionaries in d then the iteration would require to write 50 for nested loops.

Comment: I don't follow.  You don't have to write any nested for loops.  Try using your second `d` dictionary.  You'll see `get_values(d)` produces `[2, 6, 5]`.

Comment: My bad I did not see that you were using recursion. Your solution works as well and that was what I initially was thinking with try except. But If you look the last edit I also need the keys of the dict.